# Angular Material - dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material, dropdown

I have a dropdown within a `md-input-container`.

```html
<md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
   <label>Domain</label>
   <md-select formControlName="domain" id="domain" style="min-width: 170px;">
      <md-option *ngFor="let domain of userDomains" [value]="domain">
          {{domain}}
      </md-option>
   </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

I get this error:

> `md-input-container` must contain an `mdInput` directive. Did you forget to add `mdInput` to the native input or textarea element?

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't even need to put `md-select` in `md-input-container`! It looks like you're refering to the wrong Material docs!

Comment: Here's the [**docs**](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) for `md-select`!

Answer (score 3):

Like the **[docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview)** state...

> `<md-input-container>` is a wrapper for native **input** and **textarea** elements.

.. of which a `select` is neither. Besides that `mdInput` directive needs to be applied.

So from my understanding this does not work with `md-select`, despite trying to add the `mdInput` (which I tried) to it.